# Empirical mean vs mathematical one

Tags: statistics

Let's say we have a $X$ a random variable of $U[0;1]$ where $U$ denotes the uniform distribution. I have computed the empirical mean by $\text{empmean} = sum(X)/ length(X)$ and the mathematical one $\text{mathmean} = (1+0)/2$, and I want to see of the empirical mean result is expected, should I check if  $\text{empmean}\ge \text{mathmean}$?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE, what do you mean by `sum(X)/length(X)`? which values of $X$ are you using?

Comment: In practice you want the empirical mean to equate the mathematical mean. Theoretically, to do this, you'd need the distribution of $U_1 + \ldots + U_n,$ where the $U_k$ are i.i.d. uniform. This distribution may be well approximated by $\mathsf{Norm}(\frac{n}{2}, \frac{n}{6})$ (in fact, as low as $n = 6$ provides a very good approximation). Using this approximation, then the mean will have approximate distribution $\mathsf{Norm}(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{6n})$ and you can calculate the deviations from $\frac{1}{2}$ in the usual way.

Comment: @caverac values that are as William said, $U_1 + ... + U_n$ each $U_k$ is uniformally distributed.

Comment: @WilliamM. I get that, but I have this question, I got the mathematical mean and the empirical mean, and the question is whether  the empirical one is expected, and surely I don't need any approximation till now, only the question simply

Comment: I think checking if $empmean >= mathmean$ makes sense, but I am not sure. I don't want to approximate to normal distribution.

Comment: The mean of $n$ uniform random variables will be symmetric around $1/2$, which is the mathematical mean. So, if you had $m$ samples with $n$ uniform random variables each, you can check whether or not about half of these samples satisfy `emp_mean` $\geq$ `math_mean`,

Comment: Yes, but my question is exactly around `will be symmetric around 1/2` and not exactly 1/2, so if it is less than 1/2...

Comment: You are sampling i.i.d. from a symmetric continuous distribution, so the probability that the sample mean $\bar X = \frac1n\sum X_i$ is equal to to the population mean $\mathbb E[X]$ is $\mathbb P(\bar X=\mathbb E[X])= 0$ (because it is a continuous distribution) and the probability it is greater is equal to the probability it is less (because it is a symmetric distribution) so  $\mathbb P(\bar X>\mathbb E[X])=\mathbb P(\bar X<\mathbb E[X])$.  Since the three probabilities add up to $1$ you can say $\mathbb P(\bar X>\mathbb E[X])=\frac12$ and $\mathbb P(\bar X\ge\mathbb E[X])=\frac12$

Comment: Yes, I totally get, that question of `is this result expected` is not mine, it s in the textbook, and I didn't know how to approach it.